# Got a little snippy with Boss should I apologize

Tags: manager, conflict, conflict-resolution

I got a little snippy with my Boss because we agreed to hire someone and then he starts asking questions or pushing back on it after we agreed to it. Anyways I snapped back and told him if he wanted me to list everything on why we would need this person again and all the work the current team does and we are at capacity. It seems like I got Snippy to me but not sure.
Anyways should I apologize or leave it as is

Comment: What is the applicable culture here? Are you in America, the Netherlands, India, or somewhere else?

Comment: I am in America

Answer (score 14):

**It never hurts to maintain a good working relationship with your boss.**

If you feel you "got snippy", then you may gently, briefly, and politely apologize to your boss either via a **short email** or via a **short chat** in his office when he is not too busy. Depending on your boss' response to this apology, you will know his view of your behavior/acts, and you can handle similar situations better in the future.

Even if you were not really snippy in your manager's view, and therefore, he may be a little bit surprised with your apology, he would still appreciate your way of wanting to maintain a good working relationship with him.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like he might be having second thoughts about the candidate, it happens sometimes.  If I were you I'd say you are sorry and move one.

It's possible that after your boss reflected on his initial decision there was something about the candidate he didn't like, but couldn't quite put his finger on, that's why he started asking you questions.

It's a good sign that he respects your opinions and trusts you. Good bosses are hard to find so treat him well and he'll do the same for you.

Answer (score 2):

Why wouldn’t you apologize to someone if you feel that you were snippy? Sometimes how we say something makes more of an impression than what we said. Only the people who heard your exchange can tell you whether or not you were out of line.

An apology costs you nothing, and gives you an opportunity to do what you should have done the first time, which is figure out why your boss is having second thoughts about the decision.

> I was kind of cranky the other day, and I’m sorry I snapped at you. Our team really does need another person. What is your main concern about what we agreed to? Do you need me to write up the things we talked about?

Answer (score -1):

In my eyes, **what you said was not inappropriate or wrong**.

If your felt your tone was a bit harsh, I would first explain your intent of your response, that your want the new hire to be hired for the right reasons and then that your tone could have been better. It should be fine for team members to help ensure a new hire is right fit for the job need and by asking questions, as long as you are listening to your managers rlfeedback.

Did your boss state why he may be having second thoughts? Try to get a sense why he may be having second thoughts. It is

Unless something else happens, **I would leave it be**.